# Jogar variáveis para serem parâmetros na API

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, api, restful

Tenho um site e para entrar nele precisa logar, e os dados são: cpf e email. E tenho uma API que preciso jogar as variáveis cpf e email para serem parâmetros na api, porém não tenho muito conhecimento em api e também apenas tenho o link dela.

Preciso jogar esses dados pois cada usuário terá dados diferentes, e a api vai precisar desses dados no parâmetro para fazer um select e buscar dados da pessoa cadastrada com o cpf e email.

ex.: http://api/api/TRCKCLICODCPF=12345678901&EMAIL=fulano%40email.com

Consumindo API:

```
 function load(){

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://api/api/TRCKCLICODCPF=12345678901&EMAIL=fulano%40email.com");



  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var resposta = xhr.responseText;
      // console.log("ola1");
      var clientes = JSON.parse(resposta);
      // console.log("ola2");
      // console.log(clientes);

      for (var i =0; i < 1; i++){
          // console.log("ola3");
         var clientes_1 = clientes.TRACKER[i];
         AdicionaNome(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCPF(clientes_1);
         AdicionaProduto(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCidade(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCodigoProduto(clientes_1);
         AdicionaCodigoCliente(clientes_1);
         AdicionaStatus(clientes_1);
         ActiveStatusImage(clientes_1);
         ActiveOnlyPostagem(clientes_1);
         adicionaClienteNaTabelaViagem(clientes_1);
         ActiveQtdViagem(clientes_1);


     }

  });

  xhr.send();
      }
      window.onload = load;
```

***Eu mudei o link da api, só é um exemplo***

Answer (score 0):

Um método interessante é acessar via `Curl`, é semelhante a uma requisição ajax, mas com `PHP`, verifique também se a API tem alguma documentação abrangente...

Geralmente para autenticação o método é GET, então seria algo assim...

**PHP**

```
$url="http://api/api/TRCKCLICODCPF=12345678901&EMAIL=fulano%40email.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml)
```

Assim sua API não será visível a qualquer usuário caso fosse acessada no cliente...

Comment: E eu jogo esse código onde?

Comment: Crie o arquivo PHP do código, e acesse como quiser, eu recomendo acessar por ajax, ele vai te devolver o retorno da API, é lógico que terá de adapta-lo a sua aplicação. Caso não entenda o código acima, aqui no site e em outros tem tudo que precisa sobre acessar funções, curl e ajax, basta procurar...

Comment: Ah, eu fiz isso. Coloquei na pergunta, pode olhar e ver se é isso mesmo que voce está falando?

Comment: Você esta consumindo a API no cliente, nunca fiz isso então não posso dizer o que fazer, mas pelo que vi é baseada em XML, curl também tem suporte a XML, vou editar com um exemplo mais simples.

Comment: está local, eu não tenho acesso, na verdade nunca exponha um link de API privada aqui no site :)

Comment: eu modifiquei ela kkk foi só um exemplo